# My api is working on postman well but the api request from app is giving 500 error

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http-status-code-500

```
       curl --location --request POST 'https://myzoo.asia/api/delivery_boy_login' \
--header 'Keydata: 8741214584542' \
--header 'Cookie: ci_session=pqjv08gks7q6ss98jufhts3gseu33qtn' \
--form 'phone_number="01782056565"' \
--form 'password="12345678"'
```

This is my curl after successful api request from postman. I tried many ways from flutter for api request but it is giving 500 server error.

```
Map bodys = {
      'phone_number' : '01782056565',
      'password' : '12345678',

    };
   Map <String, String>  headerMap = {
     'Keydata' : '8741214584542',



// "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"


};
    var bodyString = json.encode(bodys);
    print("started working on POST REQUEST $bodyString $headerMap $apiURL");
    response = await http.post(apiURL,
        body: bodyString, headers: headerMap,);
    print("Response code: ${response.statusCode}");
    // print('response code from function: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('response code from function: ${response.body}');
    print(apiURL);
    // print(response.body);
  }
```

Other test api is working fine in this function but no luck for this api. What I am doing wrong.??? Please help.

Comment: Probably a CORS issue at the server end

Answer (score 0):

From curl's header it is written as a form data post request. Please try the api request like the following to send form data

```
Map <String, String>  headerMap = {
     'Keydata' : '8741214584542'
}

var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", apiURL);
request.headers.addAll(headers);
request.fields['phone_number'] = '01782084390';
request.fields['password'] = '12345678';

 var response = await request.send();
  var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
  var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
  print(responseString);

  if (response.statusCode == 200)
  {
     print("response successful");
  }
```

Comment: Not working. I tried multipart also but no luck . The api is working from postman perfectly. I edited my curl in post . Please check again and if possible someone check from your side. Thanks

Comment: What's the status code, now showing?

Comment: 500 internal server error from flutter. same header and body is working in postman.

Comment: I checked by adding the cookie header too. It always throws unauthorised. Please check the api. I don't think it's an issue from flutter

Comment: @KaushikChandru are you getting 500 status code?

Comment: Yeah and in html body i see unauthorised too inside some html tags

Comment: @KaushikChandru so what can be the issue? Tried every possible way.

Comment: There can be 2 possible reasons. 1. Remove the cookie if it's used. 2. Check for cors issue. Please check these 2 in api